# Ionic Platform Commands Fail With 'Cannot read property 'split' of undefined' Out of nowhere

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have been working out of the same ionic application for 4 to 5 months.

I released today to app store and had to make some updates to my environment to be able to compile down. I don't specifically recall anything that would cause this issue, but now if I try to run `ionic platform add ios` from this project directory, it fails with the following:

```
    $ ionic platform add ios
    Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
    Running command: /Users/Me/Source/Repos/mobile-app/hooks/before_platform_add/init_directories.js /Users/Me/Source/Repos/mobile-app
    Adding ios project...
    iOS project created with cordova-ios@3.9.1
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
        at default_CFBundleVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/ios_parser.js:306:19)
        at ios_parser.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/ios_parser.js:79:59)
        at ios_parser.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/ios_parser.js:264:17)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:138:31
        at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
        at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
        at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
```

I have another ionic/cordova application in a directory next to it that works fine, so I don't believe it has anything to do with my environment.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm several times. Removed `node_modules` from both my mac and the project and same result.

This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, and tracked the issue down to a hook. I guess your "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" error might have been caused by something different in your project, but maybe the following can help someone else.

Here it started to fail when I followed [Cordova recommendation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/) and changed the way the [Cordova Patch Platform hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordovahook-patch-platform) was loaded from a simple file in `hooks/after_prepare` to a custom `<hook>` tag in `config.xml`.